# IllegalStateException: Fragment FiltroOpcao not attached to a context.- Android Error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying get item selected from user to fragment formulary on my Android app, following the [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) this is possible using this methods from the library, i tried implement this methods and your Interface in my DialogFragment and get it on my fragment formulary, but, the error is returned when i click on the button necessary to open Dialog Fragment.
This is my Dialog Fragment class:

```
public class FiltroOpcao extends DialogFragment {
    OnFiltroEscolhido listener;
    private final String[] filtroAnuncio = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filtro_array);

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            listener = (OnFiltroEscolhido) getTargetFragment();
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+"Deve ser implementado");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Filtrar por:")
                .setItems(R.array.filtro_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listener.pegarFiltro(filtroAnuncio[which]);
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();

    }
    public interface OnFiltroEscolhido{
        void pegarFiltro (String escolha);
    }
}
```

And it is where i called the DialogFragment and the crash happens on my VendaFragment fragment class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                FiltroOpcao filtroOpcao = new FiltroOpcao();
                filtroOpcao.setTargetFragment(VendaFragment.this, 1);
                filtroOpcao.show(VendaFragment.this.getChildFragmentManager(), "FiltroOpcao");

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private final String[] filtroAnuncio = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filtro_array);
```

Probably, `getResources()` is the problem because you are using it before the fragment was attached.

Try to move the initialization of `filtroAnuncio` to `onCreateDialog()`

```
private String[] filtroAnuncio;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    filtroAnuncio = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filtro_array);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Filtrar por:")
            .setItems(R.array.filtro_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    listener.pegarFiltro(filtroAnuncio[which]);
                }
            });

    return builder.create();

}
```

Comment: This work fine, thanks, i'll to implement and choose your answer

Comment: Currently the error returned is "that does not belong to this FragmentManager!", but it is other thing, the original issue you resolve to me